# Hardware or Software failure? [RAID5]

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, software-raid

I have a raid5 system containing of 4 Samsung SpinPoint F4 Hard disks configured for auto spin-down after 20 Minutes. It is a Linux Software raid.

Today I noticed that upon access to the network storage the explorer in windows and Linux (caja) locks. I then had a look at the raid (normally I would get an e-mail, if something isn't right).

Now I am currently exploring the issue and the question occurs: Hardware or software? The Hard drive in question is /dev/sde, as this completely spams my dmesg:

```
[  514.321832] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  514.321849] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  514.321853] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[  514.321856] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  514.321858] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] CDB: 
[  514.321859] Read(10): 28 00 d7 02 00 38 00 00 10 00
[  514.321867] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3607232568
[  514.321898] ata5: EH complete
[  514.785181] raid5_end_read_request: 22 callbacks suppressed
[  514.785198] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607230520 on sde1)
[  514.785204] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607230528 on sde1)
[  519.849195] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x3 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  519.849201] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[  519.849204] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  519.849209] ata5.00: cmd 60/40:00:10:02:02/05:00:d7:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 688128 in
         res 41/40:00:60:06:02/00:00:d7:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[  519.849212] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  519.849214] ata5.00: error: { UNC }
[  519.861716] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  519.861806] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  519.861811] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[  519.861814] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  519.861816] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] CDB: 
[  519.861818] Read(10): 28 00 d7 02 02 10 00 05 40 00
[  519.861826] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3607234144
[  519.861874] ata5: EH complete
[  525.035364] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x18 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  525.035369] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[  525.035373] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  525.035378] ata5.00: cmd 60/80:18:60:06:02/00:00:d7:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 65536 in
         res 41/40:00:60:06:02/00:00:d7:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[  525.035381] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  525.035382] ata5.00: error: { UNC }
[  525.047886] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  525.047907] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  525.047910] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[  525.047914] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  525.047916] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] CDB: 
[  525.047918] Read(10): 28 00 d7 02 06 60 00 00 80 00
[  525.047925] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3607234144
[  525.047962] ata5: EH complete
[  525.072001] md: md0: resync done.
[  525.541340] RAID conf printout:
[  525.541346]  --- level:5 rd:4 wd:4
[  525.541349]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb1
[  525.541350]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdc1
[  525.541352]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdd1
[  525.541354]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sde1
[  525.611488] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232096 on sde1)
[  525.611507] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232104 on sde1)
[  525.611511] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232112 on sde1)
[  525.611515] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232120 on sde1)
[  525.611518] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232128 on sde1)
[  525.611522] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232136 on sde1)
[  525.611525] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232144 on sde1)
[  525.611528] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232152 on sde1)
[  525.611531] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232160 on sde1)
[  525.611534] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232168 on sde1)
```

Smart does not show any errors, but reading the smart data is incredibly slow:

```
smartctl 6.3 2014-07-26 r3976 [x86_64-linux-3.19.2-gentoo] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SAMSUNG SpinPoint F4 EG (AF)
Device Model:     SAMSUNG HD204UI
Serial Number:    S2HGJ1AZ902089
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0024e9 00401ea85
Firmware Version: 1AQ10001
User Capacity:    2.000.398.934.016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Wed Jan 13 10:39:37 2016 CET

==> WARNING: Using smartmontools or hdparm with this
drive may result in data loss due to a firmware bug.
****** THIS DRIVE MAY OR MAY NOT BE AFFECTED! ******
Buggy and fixed firmware report same version number!
See the following web pages for details:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223571en
http://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/SamsungF4EGBadBlocks

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (21180) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 353) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       416
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   068   045   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       9953
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       7671
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2791
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       669
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       24623703
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6024
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   064   060   000    Old_age   Always       -       25 (Min/Max 13/41)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       81
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7679

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed [00% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

But also `/proc/mdstat` shows:

```
Personalities : [linear] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid5 sdb1[0] sdc1[1] sdd1[2] sde1[4]
      5860147200 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

A few minutes ago, it was in resync state with this result:

```
[  525.047962] ata5: EH complete
[  525.072001] md: md0: resync done.
[  525.541340] RAID conf printout:
[  525.541346]  --- level:5 rd:4 wd:4
[  525.541349]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb1
[  525.541350]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdc1
[  525.541352]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdd1
[  525.541354]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sde1
```

But after resyncing, there still comes:

```
[  525.611488] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232096 on sde1)
[  525.611507] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232104 on sde1)
[  525.611511] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232112 on sde1)
[  525.611515] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232120 on sde1)
[  525.611518] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232128 on sde1)
[  525.611522] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232136 on sde1)
[  525.611525] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232144 on sde1)
[  525.611528] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232152 on sde1)
[  525.611531] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232160 on sde1)
[  525.611534] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 3607232168 on sde1)
```

I cant figure out, what the problem is. Can someone help me figuring it out?

Comment: Funny, it started to operate normally again. But i still want to investigate this matter...

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the drive itself, specifically because it always seems to be raising the same sectors on the same drive, which are all very close together physically. In fact, looking at them closely, entirely sequential. I have seen almost completely failed drives previously, where they're making an awful grinding noise, show perfect SMART results. It's not impossible that SMART hasn't caught them.

Personally, I'd be inclined to back up my data and further test the drive, running a thorough read test across it. I wouldn't trust that the error has now gone away, especially as you're using RAID5, which only has fault tolerance for one drive failing at a time (and if you're forced to replace and rebuild the array, depending on the amount of data you could be waiting for a day or longer).

Either way, now is the time to make sure all your backups are up to date and if you have chance run a proper test over it. SMART values are great for a quick overview, but I think you'd benefit from further diagnostic. It's likely there isn't a serious failure at this stage, but it could develop.

Comment: Thanks. I guess so to. I have plugged in my spare drive now and waiting for the rebuild to be finished.

Comment: Could this be an issue with spindown and spinup? If the HDDs are Spinned up i can manually read all sectors correctly using hdparm...

Comment: @Nidhoegger I suppose it's not impossible but I think it's likely more a fault with those specific sectors as it seems to always be pointing at the same part of the drive. Spin up issues would usually account for long delays before being able to read or write data.

Comment: I have a long delay (about 10 - 15 seconds) before beeing able to read. and the sectors that are read are always the beginnings of the files i want to read upon spinup... I backed up all data and I think ill investigate this a bit further...

Comment: maybe its a problem with staggered spinup...